# Prevent OSX firewall from popping up when developing AppEngine Go Application

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I'm currently locally developing an AppEngine app using the Go programming language. My operating system is Mac OS X 10.8.3.

I keep AppEngine's development server (dev_appserver.py) running as I develop. Every time I save one of my application files (which the server is watching for changes), the OS X firewall dialog pops up saying "Do you want to allow _go_app to receive incoming connections?". The dialog is only visible for less than a second before it disappears again.

How can I get it to stop popping up all the time? I've tried having explicit rules in the OS X firewall for both the _go_app application and simply Python to accept or deny incoming connections, but not matter what it keeps (briefly) popping up.

Comment: dont know apple firewall, but instead of this, i really could recommend you Little Snitch instead, i dont have any problems with it, just define the rules when an app tries todo something. http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index-de.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if something changed, but I was getting this error using the GCloud SDK bundled `dev_appserver.py`. (2019-02-03, MacOS Mojave/10.14, Google Cloud SDK 232.0.0) with Go 1.11.

With Go 1.11, binding explicitly to `localhost` helps:

```golang
host := ""
if os.Getenv("NODE_ENV") == "development" {
  host = "localhost"
  log.Printf("Binding to 'localhost' only for '%s'", envPurpose)
}

srv := &http.Server{
  Handler:      r,
  Addr:         fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", host, port),
  WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
  ReadTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
}

log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

EDIT: But, while this prevented the "deny/allow" popup on the initial start, it didn't help on automatic restarts *unless* I didn't explicitly declare handlers in the `app.yaml` file. Clearly, there's more going on under the hood.

However, with "bare" `app.yaml` files, it worked as desired for me.

Comment: Confirmed, binding to localhost suppresses the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Talked to the App Engine people on Google Groups, apparently this is fixed in the newest build of the SDK (1.8.1).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the firewall popup when I run `goapp serve`, but I do get it when I run `go test` with anything that uses the `google.golang.org/appengine/aetest` package. To fix this, I needed to patch two files to force all the test servers to only listen on `localhost`. I submitted a pull request, so maybe this will get fixed upstream: https://github.com/golang/appengine/pull/25

`$GOPATH/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/main_vm.go` line 25; change:

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, http.HandlerFunc(handleHTTP)); err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("http.ListenAndServe: %v", err)
}
```

to:

```
host := ""
if IsDevAppServer() {
  host = "localhost"
}
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, http.HandlerFunc(handleHTTP)); err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("http.ListenAndServe: %v", err)
}
```

I also needed to patch `$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/portpicker/portpicker/__init__.py` line 79:

```
sock.bind(('', port))
```

to:

```
sock.bind(('localhost', port))
```